# Estrutura de rotas do Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Tenho a seguinte rota:

```
$route_pri = $this->uri->segment(1);
$route_sec = ($this->uri->segment(2)==true) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : '';
$route_three = ($this->uri->segment(3)==true) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : '';

$second = ($this->uri->segment(2)==true) ? $this->uri->segment(1).'/(:any)' : $this->uri->segment(1);
$second = ($this->uri->segment(3)==true) ? $second.'/(:any)' : $second;

$route[$second] = 'leftcontent/allowed/'.$route_pri.'/'.$route_sec.'/'.$route_three;
```

Qual seria a melhor forma de organizar ela?
Eu Não quero ter que digitar todas as rotas que eu preciso traçar pra cada uma, por isso, dessa forma eu consigo recuperar, só achei desorganizado.

Comment: Você está montando as rotas dinamicamente? porque?

Answer (score 2):

O Codeigniter disponibiliza um arquivo de configuração para tratar apenas de rotas. Esse arquivo fica no **application/config/routes.php**. Caso queira saber todas as possibilidades disponíveis aconselho ler a  [documentação.](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Sim, é nele mesmo que eu montei estas rotas, de forma automática, porque se fossem manuais, eu teria que montar ao menos 10 rotas diferentes, e dessa forma, ele vai roteando como eu preciso, só que achei desorganizado essa forma, talvez a nomenclatura não esteja adequada.

Comment: Tem como você explicar melhor como essa sua rota funciona? Pelo que entendi você está mandando para a classe leftcontent e executando o métido allowed e como parâmetro você está passando 3 argumentos que o usuário pode digitar na url. É isso?

Comment: Sim, são links. De cada um... e caso não exista, levo para o 404.

Comment: Talvez a melhor alternativa seria fazer essa tratativa no seu método. Já que está tudo indo para o mesmo método da mesma classe, nesse método você verifica a url e faz oq tiver que fazer de acordo com os dados que chegar. Uma boa forma de você não precisar ficar reescrevendo código e poluindo seu método é usar uma função para isso. A primeira coisa que seu métido faz é chamar essa função que pega os valores da url e devolve oq você precisa.

Comment: Não falei mas você pode construir um arquivo helper e fazer o carregamento dele, e qualquer função que você definir lá estará disponível em qualquer lugar da sua aplicação